# Glide Library Error or Application Crash while Adding the Fragment and Also show image on that specific problem

Tags: java, android, android-glide

You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed.

```
 fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid());

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(isAdded()) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    assert user != null;
                    username.setText(user.getUsername());
                    if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")) {
                        image_profile.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    } else {
                        Glide.with(ProfileFragment.this).load(user.getImageURL()).into(image_profile);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

My Application Crashes When I Add the Fragment.

Comment: Thanx Buudy I am Also Trying the post the Answer of that Question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try your code like this:

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(isAdded()) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            assert user != null;
            username.setText(user.getUsername());
            if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")) {
                image_profile.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            } else {
                if(getAcivity()!=null && !getAcivity().isFinishing())
                    Glide.with(getAcivity()).load(user.getImageURL()).into(image_profile);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are add any fragment. The application is crashing then you have to check First the Fragment is added OR Not.

This can cause of Two Errors.
1st [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53693826/11458932) is ALso on the Stackoverflow.

2nd Problem is that you are getting the Crash from another activity please use the **NameOFActivity.this** Or **getApplicationContext()** Then goto that fragment OR activity on which your are doing that spacific task and Add the 1st Solution